# Remove empty values from array within array using php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to remove Array[1] from this group array,since its having null value in two field???.I tried using array_chunk and array_filter but not getting.If any help that is great !!!!!!

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product] => 3
                [processing_id] => 33
                [quantity] => 50
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [product] => 
                [processing_id] => 33
                [quantity] => 
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function (array $entry) {
    return $entry['product'] && $entry['quantity'];
});
```

Modify the callback to what exactly the condition is. Here entries are kept only if both `product` and `quantity` are something *truthy*.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($array)

array_filter: "If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed." This means that elements with values NULL, 0, '0', '', FALSE, array() will be removed too.

The other option is doing

array_diff($array, array(''))

which will remove elements with values NULL, '' and FALSE.
```